# How can I make this Custom Control and Android

Tags: android, user-controls

I want to make a custom control in Android.

Actually, I want to extends a EditText with one Button and one TextView. (Like below picture)

[My Custom Control Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhDZz.png)

I have not problem with listener. I want just make a custom control that contains 3 controls. (EditText, Button and TextView)

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you explain how you will extend an Edittext with one Button and one TextView .

Comment: Did you see my attached picture?

Comment: Please specify what did you mean by custom control

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Linear layout with orientation = horizontal .
Then create an edittext and a button in it .
In java code ,set onClicklistener on button and then get the value of edittext by    [edittext].getText().toString() ;

Comment: I know. I can design and programming in java. I want make a user control.

Comment: <com.mysite.myname.MyEditText

/>

Comment: User control will be through setOnClickListener

Comment: I have not problem with listener. I want just make a user control that contains 3 controls. (EditText, Button and TextView)

Answer (score 0):

Control means you want to perform any action (a similar action i understand from your explaination) on click of any of the three?

If so, have a specific method which will be called on click of each of the items and alter them according to your choice.

Is this what you meant by user control?

Comment: Excuse me. My mean is Custom Control. (I edited main question)